# How to create a more accurate Group ID using SAS, SQL, or pseudocode

Tags: sql, sas, data-science, data-analysis, pseudocode

I have big dataset and part of it looks like the below. Each set of the same KEY1 (or KEY2) values are supposed to represent the same group:

```
YEAR    KEY1   KEY2
1998    218    883
1999    218    883
2000    218    883
2001    218    883
1995    300    633
1996    300    633
1997    300    633
2003    822    119
2004    822    119
2005    822    119
2005    992    476
```

I was using KEY1 to represent each group however there are some groups where KEY1 is inconsistent:

```
YEAR    KEY1    KEY2
2002    712     683
2003    344     683
2004    712     683
```

KEY2 can also be inconsistent:

```
YEAR    KEY1    KEY2
2002    473     588
2003    473     588
2004    473     957
```

I'm treating the "344" and "957" as data errors, and all other inconsistencies in KEY1 and KEY2

My goal: create a variable called GROUPID thats more accurate at grouping than just using KEY1

Other things to note:

1. years are not always consecutive
2. KEY1 is more accurate than KEY2
3. possibility that both KEY1 and KEY2 can be inconsistent for the same group
4. dataset is large so I cant search through it manually

Possible solutions:

1. A program that searches through the whole dataset and returns the problem rows for KEY1 so I can copy KEY1 to GROUPID and then manually edit them
2. A program that can switch between using KEY1 and KEY2 depending on which creates a larger group. Then create a GROUPID that can leverage this.

Right now I'm just using KEY1. What might the SAS, SQL, or pseudocode look like for either of the above solutions? I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: Hey Mike, check out this question here. It looks like it's doing something similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900170/sas-hash-tables-is-there-a-way-to-find-join-on-different-keys-or-have-optional/

Comment: My first thought would be to use a window function to get the count of distinct values of KEY1 for each value of KEY2. When that count is greater than 1, KEY2 might be the better key.

Comment: I would just concatenate the 2 fields to make a unique composite key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one sql fiddle that serves as a solution using MS SQL Server. With large datasets, the use of indexed temp tables will outperform common table expressions. However, this is just fiddle where improvements may be possible with time permitting.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3c3a7/5)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyData( Year INT, Key1 INT, Key2 INT )
INSERT INTO MyData VALUES
(1998,    218,    883),
(1999,    218,    883),
(2000,    218,    883),
(2001,    218,    883),
(1995,    300,    633),
(1996,    300,    633),
(1997,    300,    633),
(2003,    822,    119),
(2004,    822,    119),
(2005,    822,    119),
(2005,    992,    476),
--
(2002,    712,    683),
(2003,    344,    683),
(2004,    712,    683),
(2002,    473,    588),
(2003,    473,    588),
(2004,    473,    957),
--
(2002,    712,    222),
(2003,    344,    222),
(2004,    712,    222),
(2002,    473,    111),
(2003,    473,    111),
(2004,    473,    111)
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH DataInSomeOrder AS
(
    SELECT Year,Key1,Key2, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  
    FROM MyData 
),
InstancesOfKeys AS
(
    SELECT Year,Key1,Key2,Key1InstanceNumber,Key2InstanceNumber,RowNumber FROM (
        SELECT Year,Key1,Key2,RowNumber,
            Key1InstanceNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY RowNumber),
            Key2InstanceNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Key2 ORDER BY RowNumber)
        FROM DataInSomeOrder
    )AS X 
)
SELECT 
    D.Year, D.Key1, D.Key2, D.RowNumber,
    DuplicateKeyNumber = CASE WHEN K1.Year IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END   
FROM 
    InstancesOfKeys D
    LEFT JOIN InstancesOfKeys K1 ON K1.Key1=D.Key1 AND K1.Key2=D.Key2 AND K1.Key1InstanceNumber=1
WHERE
    (D.Key1InstanceNumber<>D.Key2InstanceNumber) 
    AND
    (K1.Key1InstanceNumber IS NULL OR K1.Key1InstanceNumber<>K1.Key2InstanceNumber)
ORDER BY 
    D.RowNumber
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3c3a7/5/0)**:

```
| Year | Key1 | Key2 | RowNumber | DuplicateKeyNumber |
|------|------|------|-----------|--------------------|
| 2003 |  344 |  683 |        13 |                  1 |
| 2004 |  473 |  957 |        17 |                  2 |
| 2002 |  712 |  222 |        18 |                  2 |
| 2004 |  712 |  222 |        20 |                  2 |
| 2002 |  473 |  111 |        21 |                  2 |
| 2003 |  473 |  111 |        22 |                  2 |
| 2004 |  473 |  111 |        23 |                  2 |
```

Without using CTE's

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3c3a7/5)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    D.Year, D.Key1, D.Key2, D.RowNumber,
    DuplicateKeyNumber = CASE WHEN K1.Year IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END   
FROM 
    (
       SELECT Year,Key1,Key2,Key1InstanceNumber,Key2InstanceNumber,RowNumber FROM (
          SELECT Year,Key1,Key2,RowNumber,
              Key1InstanceNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY RowNumber),
              Key2InstanceNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Key2 ORDER BY RowNumber)
          FROM 
          (
             SELECT Year,Key1,Key2, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  
             FROM MyData
          ) SomeOrder  
      )AS X 
    )AS D
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
       SELECT Year,Key1,Key2,Key1InstanceNumber,Key2InstanceNumber,RowNumber FROM (
           SELECT Year,Key1,Key2,RowNumber,
               Key1InstanceNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY RowNumber),
               Key2InstanceNumber = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Key2 ORDER BY RowNumber)
           FROM 
           (
              SELECT Year,Key1,Key2, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  
              FROM MyData
           ) SomeOrder  
       )AS X 
     )AS K1 ON K1.Key1=D.Key1 AND K1.Key2=D.Key2 AND K1.Key1InstanceNumber=1
WHERE
    (D.Key1InstanceNumber<>D.Key2InstanceNumber) 
    AND
    (K1.Key1InstanceNumber IS NULL OR K1.Key1InstanceNumber<>K1.Key2InstanceNumber)
ORDER BY 
    D.RowNumber
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3c3a7/5/0)**:

```
| Year | Key1 | Key2 | RowNumber | DuplicateKeyNumber |
|------|------|------|-----------|--------------------|
| 2003 |  344 |  683 |        13 |                  1 |
| 2004 |  473 |  957 |        17 |                  2 |
| 2002 |  712 |  222 |        18 |                  2 |
| 2004 |  712 |  222 |        20 |                  2 |
| 2002 |  473 |  111 |        21 |                  2 |
| 2003 |  473 |  111 |        22 |                  2 |
| 2004 |  473 |  111 |        23 |                  2 |
```

Comment: That won't work in SAS, it doesn't support WITH() unless the OP has MS SQL and can use SQL pass through.

Comment: That spoils the fun :)  Added a bit more verbose fiddle without using CTE's

Comment: RANK and PARTITION are also not supported :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use your way back machine to dial up 2004's "How to group people by their first name OR last name" and see

> Given a set of pairs (key1, key2), find the distinct groups of
> pairs such that each pair in a group has this property:
>
> - key1 matches key1 of any other pair in the group.
>   OR
>   key2 matches key2 of any other pair in the group.

> an iterative way using version 9 hashes.
> Two hashes maintain the groupId assigned to each key value.
> Two additional hashes are used to maintain group mapping paths.
> When the data can be passed without causing a mapping, then the groups have
> been fully determined.
> Then a final pass is done, at which point the groupIds are assigned to each
> pair.

**Sample code**

```
%let seed =
%sysfunc(mod(%sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(constant(e)),.)),2**31));

* random pair data;
data pairs;
  do id = 1 to 1e4;
    key1 = int (1e4*ranuni(&seed));
    key2 = int (1e4*ranuni(&seed));
    output;
  end;
run;

/*
data pairs;
  id + 1;
  input key1 $ key2 $;
  cards;
John Smith
George Smith
Bill Clinton
George Bush
;

data pairs;
  id + 1;
  input key1 key2 ;
  format _numeric_ 4.;
  cards;
1 2
3 2
4 5
3 6
4 2
;
*/

%let dbg = *;

data pairsWithGroupAssignments ;

  declare hash one();
  one.definekey ('key1');
  one.definedata ('key1', 'groupid');
  one.definedone();

  declare hash two();
  two.definekey ('key2');
  two.definedata ('key2', 'groupid');
  two.definedone();

  declare hash map1();
  map1.definekey ('from');
  map1.definedata ('from', 'to');
  map1.definedone();

  declare hash map2();
  map2.definekey ('from');
  map2.definedata ('from', 'to');
  map2.definedone();

  _groupId = 0;
  noMappings = 0;

  do until (noMappings and outputDone);

    doOutput = noMappings;
    noMappings = 1;

    do _n_ = 1 to numberOfPairs;

      set pairs nobs=numberOfPairs point=_n_;

      rc1 = one.find(); g1 = groupId;
      rc2 = two.find(); g2 = groupId;

      if doOutput then do;
        output;
        continue;
      end;

      &dbg.
      put id= '(' key1 +(-1) ', ' key2 +(-1) ') ' @;

      if rc1 ne 0 and rc2 ne 0 then do;
        /** /
        addboth:
        /**/
        _groupId + 1;
        groupId = _groupId;
        one.add ();
        two.add ();
        &dbg. put 'add ' key1= 'and ' key2= 'to ' groupId=;
      end;
      else
      if rc1 ne 0 and rc2 = 0 then do;
        /** /
        add1:
        /**/
        groupId = g2;
        one.add();
        &dbg. put 'add ' key1= 'to ' groupId=;
      end;
      else
      if rc1 = 0 and rc2 ne 0 then do;
        /** /
        add2:
        /**/
        groupId = g1;
        two.add();
        &dbg. put 'add ' key2= 'to ' groupId=;
      end;
      else
      if g1 > g2 then do;
        /** /
        g1g2:
        /**/

        from = g1;
        to = g2;

        * determine groupid by following map1;
        _to = to;
        do while (map1.find(key:_to) = 0);
          _to = to;
        end;

        from = g1;
        map1.replace();

        groupId = to;
        one.replace();

        &dbg. put 'add ' key1= 'to ' groupId= 'mapped from key1 group ' from;

        noMappings = 0;
      end;
      else
      if g2 > g1 then do;
        /** /
        g2g1:
        /**/

        from = g2;
        to = g1;

        * determine groupid by following map2;
        to_ = to;
        do while (map2.find(key:to_) = 0);
          to_ = to;
        end;

        from = g2;
        map2.replace();

        groupId = to;
        two.replace();

        &dbg. put 'add ' key2= 'to ' groupId= 'mapped from key2 group ' from;

        noMappings = 0;
      end;
      else do;
        /** /
        same:
        /**/
        &dbg. put rc1= rc2= g1= g2=;
      end;
    end;

    nPass + 1;

    outputDone = doOutput;
  end;

  put 'NOTE: Data iterated ' npass 'times.';

/*
  two.output(dataset:'g2');
  one.output(dataset:'g1');
  map1.output(dataset:'map1');
  map2.output(dataset:'map2');
*/
  stop;

  keep id key1 key2 groupId;
  format _numeric_ 8.;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select count(distinct groupId) into :ngroups from &syslast;

%put &=ngroups;
```

Tracking relationships or paths through a network has been discussed in
several prior [SAS-L](https://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A0=SAS-L) listserv threads over the years (<=2004).

You might also find https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples#superset
interesting or helpful.